# Findbugs too slow

Tags: findbugs

I want to run findbugs on a single class in a project of about 15k classes. I use the -onlyAnalyze option to only specify that class but still findbugs takes in the order of over 5 minutes to run on that particular class. Anyway to speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap size for the JVM?  Is FindBugs running with the server version of HotSpot?  Try using VisualVM to profile FindBugs.